# Error: Calling activity from outside of activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I do have an application which has few screens(activities). From one of them, which is support-screen, i have to be able to run email, share, other activity. So, I have added sending email option in this way:

```
 case R.id.firstColumn:
            /* Create the Intent */
            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            /* Fill it with Data */
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"elitedrumbeat@gmail.com"});
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback from customers");


            /* Send it off to the Activity-Chooser */
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
            break;
```

I proposed it will run default built in email application and will give to user option to fill out the body and then send the email. Unfortunately, logcat gives this error:

```
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3063)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3058)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     ... 11 more
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:847)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
12-25 12:06:17.074: E/AndroidRuntime(8153):     at tt.tt.tt.gui.SupportScreen.onClick(SupportScreen.java:38)
```

Googling I have found that I need to add the following line:

```
 emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Which is not preferable, but adding that line still didnt help. So, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. I have no idea why is I used context for running intent.

```
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Should be

```
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

And done, this works.